# Why am I getting warning while editing a question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing

I was trying to suggest an edit on this question [Is it possible to change playing styles in cricket?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/1695/540). When I click on edit link, it show me a warning at right side (above *How To Edit* tips) like this:

[image]

I know this warning come when we try to edit old revision of the post. But here I am trying to edit the latest revision but still it shows me the warning.

Actually when I click on edit link, it show me Rev as Max (that is wrong), but it show me the latest revision (@Michael Myers♦'s edits).

Comment: I tried it in an incognito window ([click here](http://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/1695/edit)) and got the wrong revision like you did. I had to go incognito because when I edit normally, I get the inline editor which doesn't even have the revision selector (since I have over 1k reputation).

Comment: And you are a moderator... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The check whether the edited revision is the current one didn't correctly take into account the situation where a suggested edit is improved (as in this case), which essentially creates to different revisions at exactly the same time. That's why you received this incorrect warning. This is fixed in the next build of the site.

Answer (score -1):

I would presume that while you were editing the question, a newer edit was made. But I am not sure if that's case

Comment: No. That is not a case. Because I am still getting the same warning. (I haven't edited yet.)

Comment: Interesting I just clicked on the edit button myself, and it shows the latest edit

Comment: Are you getting the warning?

Comment: nope! not at all

Comment: One more thing. When I select the latest revision (i.e. Michael Myers♦'s edits), it doesn't get selected it select the second revision (i.e. Max's edit). BUT the text in the edit box is the latest one!

Comment: sounds like an odd bug. I have no idea why that might be the case...

Comment: @posdef: Since you have >1k rep, do you have the inline editor? Perhaps this bug only exists when suggesting edits.

Comment: @MichaelMyers well actually no, i don't get the inline editor. I thought that was only for answers, not for questions. At any rate I get the "regular" edit page, but I thought it might have something to do with rep

Comment: Huh. Can you try it in an incognito window (or a different browser) just to be sure? I checked around in chat and got conflicting reports.

Comment: @michaelmyers yep then I get the same warning as the OP